useEffect is not defined
I can't understand the reason, useEffect is there, but the error says useEffect is not defined
I don't understand why useEffect is not defined, I have imported it
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import "./MainPage.css"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

 const Bjd = () => {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState('')
    const [image, setImage] = useState(undefined)
    const [data, setData] = useState({})


    const role = useSelector((state) => state.auth.role)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/request")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setData(data))
    }, [])




    
        export default Bjd

I entered imported useEffect, but the error is still the same

Please don't describe error messages; copy and paste them into the question (as text).

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular How do I ask a good question? I also recommend Jon Skeet's Writing the Perfect Question and Question Checklist.

Side note: It's probably not the problem, but you're running into one of the common fetch mistakes: You need to check whether the HTTP request succeeded (since fetch only rejects its promise on network error, not HTTP error), more in my old anemic blog here: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html

Stack Overflow is a very active place, even on the weekend. if you post a question (or answer), please stick around to respond to anything that comes up in the comments.

comment the entire fetch code inside useEffect and check if you still get the error

It looks like you need to export the component from outside the component itself
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import "./MainPage.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Bjd = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState('');
    const [image, setImage] = useState(undefined);
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    const role = useSelector((state) => state.auth.role);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/request")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setData(data));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {/* component */}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Bjd;

